# How to merge 2 arrays python (similar to SQL Join)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have 2 large arrays (500,1,23000) and another one (700,1,25000) I need to merge them. They are different

Easy example would be this:

```
a = np.array([['a', 3, 5, 6, 9], ['b', 14, 15, 56]])
b = np.array([['b', 4, 76, 44, 91, 100], ['c', 14, 15],['d',2,6,7])
```

Desired result:

`c = [['a', 3, 5, 6, 9], ['b', 4, 76, 44, 91, 100],['c', 14, 15],['d', 2, 6, 7]]`

This is part of data-preprocessing for machine learning.

Comment: If I copy-n-paste your `b` expression, I'll get an object dtype array; essentially a list of lists.  What's that have to do with `numpy`?  Where does this `'a'` list come from?  So far your question deserves to be closed as `unclear`.

Comment: Is the handling in the output of array "a" s 2nd value and array "b"s first value (the two with 'b' in front) intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be made faster (it iterates over both lists twice), but should give you what you want.

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

a = np.array([['a', 3, 5, 6, 9], ['b', 14, 15, 56]])
b = np.array([['b', 4, 76, 44, 91, 100], ['c', 14, 15],['d',2,6,7]])

def dictify(arr):
    return defaultdict(lambda : [], {x[0]: x[1:] for x in arr})

d1 = dictify(a)
d2 = dictify(b)

new_keys = set.union(set(d1.keys()), set(d2.keys()))

ans = [[k] + d1[k] + d2[k] for k in new_keys]
```

The value of `ans` is:

```
[['d', 2, 6, 7], ['c', 14, 15], ['a', 3, 5, 6, 9], ['b', 14, 15, 56, 4, 76, 44, 91, 100]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a **HACK** if you are interested, having a look at your **vague requirement**

```
a = np.array([['a', 3, 5, 6, 9], None])
b = np.array([['b', 4, 76, 44, 91, 100], ['c', 14, 15], ['d', 2, 6, 7]])
c = np.append(a, b)
d = np.delete(c, 1)
```